# MySQL DB search with partial exact math

Tags: mysql, search, fuzzy-search

I have MySQL datatable of personal parameters (about 100 per person):

```
{"id":"1", "height":"182", "hair_color":"red", "eyes_color":"haze", "day_of_birth":"25"}
```

(JSON format is just for simplicity)

I must be able to implement partial search, to be able by, say, 5-1 parameters to get the result.

QUERY: `["height":182, "hair_color":"red", "day_of_birth":"25", "skin_color":"black"]`

In the end I need list of matching row with NUMBER of matched parameters

LIKE:  `["id":"1","matched":"2"]`

And get, say "first 100" with biggest amount of matches (sure, ASAP :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to stick to an sql database, try something like the following:

```sql
select id, if (height=182,1,0)  
         + if(hair_color='red',1,0)
         +  if(day_of_birth=25,1,0)
         + if(skin_color='black',1,0) as matched
from person
order by matched desc
limit 100
```

For matching lots of entries with lots of parameters, however, there might be better choices, e.g. using a full text index like, for example, Apache Lucene / SOLR.

Comment: Hmm... never tried such attitude. Interesting.
100 if's over ~1000000 rows db... might be quite time consuming... but I'll try!

Comment: You should definitely look for some other storage engine. If keeping MySQL is a must, then have a look at Lucene (or Elastic Search). If having a relational database is a must but you happen to be to consider alternatives to MySQL, then you might have success with PostgreSQL, which offer support for various fuzzy match and multi-dimensional queries, with index. And I don't know for sure, but MariaDB might also have some interesting features in this regard.

Comment: @StephanLechner, the project is rather small so, most likely, this solution will do the trick.
But later, if it brings any profit, SOLR /Lucene was in perspective.